# Applying keras CNN to new dataset

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

Complete Keras/ML beginner here!

Given a successfully trained NN (CNN or otherwise) resulting in `my_model.h5`, I can load the model as

```
from keras import load_model
model = load_model("my_model.h5")
```

Loading a new dataset on which I simply want to **apply** my NN (not train or validate), how do I do that? As far as I understand, for each sample I feed in, I should be able to get out a score between 0 and 1 quantifying the NN's confidence in that sample being signal-like. How do I get those numbers, e.g. in the form `{sample1: score, sample2: score,...}`?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is it:

```
results = model.predict(inputData)
```

The `inputData` must have the same number of dimensions that you training data had, and the shapes must be compatible.

As it's standard, the samples are in the first dimension.

```
for res in results:
    #res is the score for a sample
```

Comment: Great, thanks! So I'll get a list out - no way of matching it to the original samples other than keeping track of the ordering of the samples I feed in?

Comment: You will get a numpy array out. (And the inputData should be a numpy array as well). The output samples are the input samples, 1 to 1. You can work with a `zip(inputData,results)` and you will have paired input/output items.